# 2 Lookups of the same object

Tags: lookup, visualforce

Facing an issue with 2 look-up fields of same object. When i used both the fields on the same page only one is getting selected.

Steps to reproduce -
1. created 2 look-up fields of same object
2. added both the fields on the same page
3. selected fist look-up value
4. selected second look-up value

After selection of second look-up value it gets populated on the first fields and the second field remain blank.

Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is this on a standard page layout? Or a visualforce page?

Comment: fields are on a visualforce page.

Comment: Can you show the VF code then?

Comment: Something wrong with your Visualforce Markup. Update the question with the mark up please.

Comment: I have done similar page previously. But it was working fine. Please check your code or post page code.

Comment: Issue get resolved :)

Actually issue was with the VF page.

---
Thank You All